# Shellsort Interval Question Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, intervals, shellsort

I need to test the efficiency of shellsort when I am using the standard interval size and also while using a non-standard size. The problem I am encountering is when I try to use my non-standard interval.

This is my Shellsort when h is equal to the standard interval size:

```
    public void shellSort() 
    {
    int inner, outer;
    int temp;
    int h = 1;

    while (h <= length / 3)
    {
      h = h * 3 + 1; 
    }

    while (h > 0) 
    {

      for (outer = h; outer < length; outer++) 
      {
        temp = data[outer];
        inner = outer;

        while (inner > h - 1 && data[inner - h] >= temp) 
        {
          data[inner] = data[inner - h];
          inner -= h;
        }
        data[inner] = temp;
      }

      h = (h - 1) / 3; 

    }

  }
```

And here is my attempt at using a prime number interval

```
      private int[]  primes = {0, 1, 3, 7, 13, 31, 97, 211, 503, 1013, 2503, 5171};
      public void shellSort() 
      {
        int inner, outer;
        int temp;
        int count = this.h.length - 1;
        int h = 1;

        h = primes[primes.length - 1] * 2 > length ? primes[primes.length - 1] : primes[primes.length - 2];

        while (h > 0) 
        {         
          for (outer = h; outer < length; outer++) 
          {
            temp = data[outer];
            inner = outer;

            while (inner > h - 1 && data[inner - h] >= temp) 
            {
              data[inner] = data[inner - h];
              inner -= h;
            }
            data[inner] = temp;
          }

          if(count - 1 > 0)           
              h = primes[count - 1];              

        }

      }
```

I am trying to compare the two based off of real time efficiency , and I can't figure out how to get this prim interval to work.

I'm trying to test:

- Shellsort performs better than O(N^2) with appropriately chosen interval sizes
- The series of interval sizes chosen is important to achieving better than O(N^2) runtime

Thank you for any help.

Comment: what's wrong with it? I take it that it isn't sorting correctly? Or do you not know how to time it?

Comment: I know how to time it, it's the intervals themselves that are throwing the shellsort method either into an infinite loop, or it isn't sorting correctly. Can anyone tell me if the prime interval calculation is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to decrement the value of `count` in each iteration of the outer loop. In your code it is still `this.h.length-1`, which is 11. Therefore, after each iteration of the outer loop you have the `if` condition `count-1 > 0` satisfied, so you set `h = this.h[count-1]`, which I believe is 2503. So, you reenter the loop.

By the way, calling the list of interval sizes `h` seriously impedes readability. You should call it at least `hs`.

Comment: trust me, I never meant to to that. I just empirically named my data, and never had a chance to rename it yet.